# Facebook API share feed popup sometimes get blocked

Tags: javascript, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have a page where you can share something.

First im logging in with FB.login()

```
FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
        sharePost(imgName,socket);
    } else {
        //do nothing if not logged in....
    }
}, {scope: 'public_profile,email,user_friends'});
```

Then im using the following share

```
FB.ui(
    {
        method: 'feed',
        link: 'myurl',
        caption: 'mycaption',
        display:'popup',
        title: 'title,
        picture:'myimg.png',
        description:'mydescription,
        name:'myname'
    },
    // callback
    function(response) {
        if (response && !response.error_code) {
            if(waitedTooLong == false)
            {
                successfullLogin(socket);
            }

            console.log("shared");
        } else {
            successfullLogin(socket);
            console.log("not shared");
        }
   }

)};
```

Sometimes it blocks the popup after logging in. Sometimes not.

I thought about removing FB.login() but I need the scope for other actions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `FB.ui` dialogs on user interaction (= mouse click), not in the asynchronous callback function of `FB.login`. Modern browser detect it as unauthorized popup and block it. Also, it´s a bad idea to present a feed dialog right after authorization. Present a Login Button and use `FB.login`, then present a Share Button and use `FB.ui` feed or `FB.ui` share.

Btw, you don´t even need to authorize the user for `FB.ui`, so you can just skip `FB.login` and use it when you really need it.